# How to merge fields and vertical lines in details section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I am working on web based application using Visual Studio 2019 Preview with SAP Crystal Reports 2016 Support Pack 7.

The report consists of 20 columns in single row. There is a requirement to show two fix headings in details section.

Report Design:
[image]

What I want is to set the first heading in first row then list records from database then set other heading and print rest of the records by merging the fields and lines of first and second heading in details sections (similar to excel “Merge Cells Function”). Heading value is set in first column but since the width of first column is too short it is not visible and looks ugly.

Current Output:
[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

The number of records between first and second heading are not fixed and fetch from database.

In addition, since there are too many columns in single row not all columns are visible in printing. Could anyone advice how to fix them while printing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group the report based on the logic of how you wish to separate the 2 groups of records.
Then, use a Group Header section to present the information you need at the top of each group.

note: if you are not familiar with Crystal, you Group by using 
***Insert, Group***
or ***Report, Group Expert***